Does time series with constant mean and constant variance implies weak stationary?
I understand that a weak stationary process has constant mean and variance as autocovariance depends only on the the lag.
However, does the reveres hold? i.e. constant mean and constant variance imply weak stationary.
I am not sure as $COV(X_i,X_{i+j})$ has component $E({X_i}X_{i+j})$ and constant variance does not guarantee this component to be constant?

Hint: use the law of total expectation to expand out the expected value of the product.

See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/413855, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/582177/, and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/379477 for very similar question.  The last looks like a duplicate.

The requirement for weak stationarity are:

$\mu_X(i) = \mathbb{E}[X_i] = \mu \text{ is independent of } i$,
$\text{Cov}(X_{i+j}, X_i) = \mathbb{E}[(X_{i+j} - \mu_X(i + j))(X_i - \mu_X(i)] \text{ is independent of } i \text{ for each integer } j$

So $COV(X_i,X_{i+j})$ has to be independent of $i$ in order for the time series to be stationary.

Rodion: Nice answer but  there's a typo in that it should be independent of $i$ and not $j$.

True, thank you!
